# i want field content only accept number and limit length in yii2 app

Tags: yii2

hi i want field content only accept number and limit length in yii2 app.

i have field i want only user fill that with number and maximum length is 11. correctly i want insert phone number in that.

i use number type and it not accept length and when i use string it is accept char and i don't want that.

please help me about that.

this is my example:

```
           public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['f_name', 'l_name', 'phone_number'], 'required'],
        [['f_name'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        [['l_name'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
        [['phone_number', 'Mobile_number'], 'number','length' => [4, 24]],
    ];
}
```

Comment: supply the following options in your form field: `['type' =>'number', 'maxlength'=>true]`

Comment: @kalu i get this error when add max length :Setting unknown property: yii\validators\NumberValidator::maxlength

Comment: check yii2 docs for the correct property. try ''lenght"

Comment: there isen;t that in yii documentation. try lenght but get error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a number validator and set its "max" to 99999999999 (11 digits) or use a match validator with a regular expression.